# Scatter plots in Grafana

Tags: dashboard, grafana

I am using a dockerized grafana to create a dashboard for historical data. I cannot see a scatter plot option in grafana graph panel.

I want to use scatter plot to display data points in range of time interval. I equally want to be able to get/display number of data points for selected intervals say 30mins, 60mins etc.

Comment: You may be intersted in https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/natel-plotly-panel / https://github.com/NatelEnergy/grafana-plotly-panel.

Comment: Seconded for the plotly panel. Does what you say in your q, and more.

Comment: This 6-year old open issue describes the feature request for Grafana, specifically non-time X-axis: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/202

Answer (score 7):

In my instance of Grafana (v8.2.3), I couldn't find the "XY Chart" mentioned in another reply, but I found different other options:

1. ["Scatter" Plugin](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/michaeldmoore-scatter-panel/) by Michael Moore: Probably the simplest one, but rather basic.
2. ["Plotly" Plugin](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/natel-plotly-panel/) by Natel Energy: More advanced and even with 3D scatter plots (and more) that uses the [Plotly](https://plotly.com/javascript/) (Javascript?) Library.
3. ["Plotly panel" Plugin](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/ae3e-plotly-panel/) by AE3E: Uses the same library but this plugin has less than a GUI and more than a coding interface, so you enter JSON and JavaScript code to generate the plot - more difficult but also very flexible, once you figured out how it works. Almost no examples are given on the plugin & GitHub page, so look things up in the [Plotly](https://plotly.com/javascript/) documentation.

## Examples

### **0. Installation:**

Installation is similar for all plugins and described in the "installation" tab on each plugin page. It might depend on your installation (e.g. I don't know how this works when using docker), but in my case of a "regular" Grafana installation, I could just type this into the console (e.g. via SSH):

```
sudo grafana-cli plugins install michaeldmoore-scatter-panel
sudo grafana-cli plugins install natel-plotly-panel
sudo grafana-cli plugins install ae3e-plotly-panel
sudo systemctl restart grafana-server
sudo systemctl status grafana-server
```

(Select the plugins you want to install, restart Grafana server and check its status (should be green and without errors). **Hint:** Save dashboards in case you were changing things before restarting Grafana, as restarting the Grafana server will delete unsaved dashboards.)

### **1. Scatter Plugin:**

- Add a new panel in a Grafana dashboard and select the "Scatter" visualization/panel.
- Start with the "Table view" to see if you receive valid results:

  - Select at least 2 fields from the database (you may use tags, but remove aggregators/selectors for the fields). To select a second field, click on the "+" icon next to the first field, scroll down and select "Fields > field".
  - Also remove "group by".
  - Format as "Table"

You should see two columns next to the timestamps.

[image: Scatter plugin table view]

(Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3TzX.png) for large image)

Now switch back from "Table view" to the graph and adjust it on the right side in the settings:

- X Axis > X Axis Field: select one of the two fields
- Y Axis > Field(s): select the other field

Could look like this:
[image: Scatter plugin graph]

(Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIk8Q.png) for large image)

### **2. Plotly Plugin (Natel):**

Prepare data similarly as for the Scatter plugin. Could look like this:

[image: Plotly 1/2]

(Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVYRq.png) for large image)

[image: Plotly 2/2]

(Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz704.png) for large image)

*Note: At least in my version, the panel didn't refresh when I changed settings. Toggle between table and graph view ("Table view" selector above the graph) to rebuild the panel.*

### **3. Plotly Panel Plugin (AE3E):**

Prepare data similarly as for the Scatter plugin. (I also added a third field which I use in the tooltip when hovering data points.)

Could look like this:

[image: Plotly Panel]

(Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QU6l.png) for large image)

Code used for the screenshot:

**Data section:**

```
[
  {
    "line": {
      "color": "rgba(255,255,255,255)",
      "width": 1
    },
    "mode": "lines",
    "type": "scatter"
  }
]
```

for "color", you can also use "green", "red" and so on. When using rgba(), first value is red (0-255), second green, then blue and last alpha channel (0 is fully transparent, 255 not transparent at all)

**Layout section:**

```
{
  "annotations": [
    {
      "showarrow": false,
      "text": "-Im{Z} [mΩ]",
      "textangle": -90,
      "x": -0.03,
      "xanchor": "right",
      "xref": "paper",
      "y": 0.5,
      "yanchor": "right",
      "yref": "paper"
    },
    {
      "showarrow": false,
      "text": "Re{Z} [mΩ]",
      "x": 0.5,
      "xanchor": "top",
      "xref": "paper",
      "y": -0.07,
      "yanchor": "top",
      "yref": "paper"
    }
  ],
  "font": {
    "color": "darkgrey"
  },
  "margin": {
    "b": 40,
    "t": 15
  },
  "paper_bgcolor": "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
  "plot_bgcolor": "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
  "xaxis": {
    "autorange": false,
    "gridcolor": "rgba(128,128,128,255)",
    "range": [
      0,
      90
    ],
    "type": "linear"
  },
  "yaxis": {
    "autorange": false,
    "gridcolor": "rgba(128,128,128,255)",
    "range": [
      -50,
      20
    ],
    "type": "linear"
  },
  "hovermode": "closest"
}
```

**Configuration section:** (unchanged)

```
{
  "displayModeBar": false
}
```

**Script section:**

```
// console.log(data)
var trace = {
  x: data.series[0].fields[1].values.buffer,
  y: data.series[0].fields[2].values.buffer,
  text: data.series[0].fields[3].values.buffer,
  mode: 'lines+markers',
  type: 'scatter',
  hovertemplate: 'Re: %{x:.4f} mΩ | Im: %{y:.4f} mΩ @ %{text:.2f} Hz'
};
  
return {data:[trace]};
```

Make sure to select fields 1 and 2 to get an XY plot. By default, 0 and 1 are selected which will result in a regular time series plot. I included a third data set (frequency) and added it to the text variable to display it in a tooltip when hovering a data point.

**Click script section:**

```
// console.log(data)
window.updateVariables({query:{'var-project':'test'}, partial: true})
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

As for Grafana v7.4 there is a new XY stat panel:

[image: Grafana 7.4 scatter plot of an Azure Data Explorer table query of two number columns:x, y]

**Older non-really answer**

When using the standard the Graph panel, you can select "Points" and unselect "Lines".

You can also mix this with lines if you do a series override:

[image: Grafana Screenshot]

This can be seen on the public Grafana instance at https://play.grafana.org/d/000000016/graph-styles?tab=visualization&orgId=1&fullscreen&edit&panelId=17 . In regards to count per period, I'm not sure if that can be done in Grafana natively, but might be possible depending on which datasource you are using.

Comment: I'm aware of the "Points" option of the Graph panel, however, it doesn't satisfy the job.

Comment: I believe the OP is using the word "scatterplot" to mean a plot where the x-axis is not necessarily time, e.g. an x-y plot of cpu load vs database hits, as opposed to time-based trends for cpu load and db hits.

Comment: If you use the XY Chart, make sure to limit the number of data points in datasource e.g. 1000.  Also sort data points by X axis value in ascending order, otherwise the chart would look truncated.

Comment: Does anyone know what happened to the XY Chart in Grafana 8 (8.2.3 in my case)? I can't find it. Found [this useful Scatter plugin](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/michaeldmoore-scatter-panel/), but I'm looking for a logarithmic x-axis in an XY graph/scatter plot.

Comment: @MatthiasLuh I am wondering the same. My best guess it that the "Trend" panel is what has replaced XY Chart. But I have yet to find confirmation...